# Make a Button's background transparent

Tags: android, button, background

I am very new to Android Studio and creating apps in general.
I have created an Image Button and uploaded an Image, problem is that I want to make the background of the Button transparent.
This is what I mean:[See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEaZG.jpg)

The background of the left button is black and I want to make it transparent, like the Right Button.

Comment: Use .png(image with transparent background) image for your left button too.

Comment: Welcome @fotiadis_m, I recommend you visit [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To add the things you had try before.

Answer (score 2):

Just put this property inside `ImageButton` tag:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

----------OR--------------

You can also user vector image for this:

1. Click on Vector Asset
   [image]
2. Click on small icon image(just below ic_android_black_24dp) 
   [image]
3. Search any icon and add to your drawable. The icon you are using is appeared in search result. use this list icon. [image]

Comment: Note that a Button looks like a button because it uses a background drawable.  SO setting a background will make it no longer look like a button as a side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```