# Removing background colour from alert buttons

Tags: android, react-native, material-design

I'm building an application with React Native, and with very little knowledge of Android. Mostly this is not a problem, but I would like to use native components for alerts. React native provides a way to launch a native alert, but there is no way to style it from React code. So I have resorted to suggestions online about using the `/res/values/styles.xml` configuration.

It's possible that it's just my lack of knowledge in Android showing here, but I can't seem to get a good solid reference of XML styling attributes, where they go, how they're structured etc.

My problem currently is that my buttons are showing up with background colours, which I don't want. I want to have standard material design text buttons like you would expect on Android. In the image below, "OK" should show up with green text, and no background.

[image]

Here is my styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#16192E</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#6fca3a</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#6fca3a</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">#16192E</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundFloating">#16192E</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/NeutralButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NeutralButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#f00</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#00f</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And if anyone can point me in the direction for figuring this stuff out myself that would also be great.

*EDIT*

This is not a question about how to change the style of a button that I have rendered onto the page in code. This question is specifically about how to style the buttons on a *built in native* android alert dialog. There does not appear to be a way to do it through JavaScript/React, and the fact that I am able to style the background, text colour, and button colour of the alert lead me to believe that it can be done through the `styles.xml` file, without having to actually write Android code to extend the Alert Dialog.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a Button's background transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499502/make-a-buttons-background-transparent)

Comment: @HassanKandil unfortunately not, although it seems like a start. I figure that the button has to have a transparent background (although I thought that would be the default anyway). If I put in under each of the styles like `NeutralButtonStyle` is doesn't seem to do anything. I assume what you linked would translate to `<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>` in the XML file but honestly I have no idea that's just a guess.

Comment: Tried changing the background of the button to another color ?

Comment: I have tried many different combinations of colours, properties etc, and none are working. The only thing I've been able to figure out, is that if I change `colorPrimary` in the root theme it changes the background color of the buttons. But nothing else has any effect. Notice that I have the `textColor` set to red (and blue for the positive), and they have no effect as you can see in the image. So I assume their wrong, but I don't know what I need to be checking, or where to even start tracing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In native Android using a Material Components theme you can customize globally the alert dialog using:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ...
    <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
 </style>
```

with:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
     <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
     <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
     <item name="buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">....</item>
  </style>
```